# XML POST successful to Datamapper, but GET request returns []

Tags: ruby, xml, datamapper

I'm trying to POST XML and store it in datamapper. The POST format response shows up and looks valid in Postman, but when I issue a GET request, [] is returned.

Here's the sample XML I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="Test"
           tests="4"
           failures="0"
           errors="0"
           skipped="4"
           time="0.002">
  <properties />

            <testcase name=“name” time="0.0" classname="classname">
          <skipped />
    </testcase>
            <testcase name="name" time="0.0" classname="classname">
          <skipped />
    </testcase>
            <testcase name="name" time="0.0" classname="classname">
          <skipped />
    </testcase>
            <testcase name="name" time="0.0" classname="classname">
          <skipped />
    </testcase>


</testsuite>
```

Sample format_response from POST

```
{"testsuite":null,"testcase":[{"skipped":null,"name":"name","time":"0.0","classname":"classname"},{"skipped":null,"name":"name","time":"0.0","classname":"classname"},{"skipped":null,"name":"name","time":"0.0","classname":"classname"},{"skipped":null,"name":"name","time":"0.0","classname":"classname"}],"name":"Test","tests":"4","failures":"0","time":"0.002","classname":"classname"}
```

Here's my model

```
class SuiteConfiguration
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :testsuite, Serial
  property :testcase, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :tests, String
  property :failures, String
  property :time, String
  property :classname, String
end
```

My Routes

```
get '/api/tests' do
  format_response(SuiteConfiguration.all, request.accept)
end

post '/api/tests' do
  body = Crack::XML.parse request.body.read

  config = SuiteConfiguration.create(
      testsuite: body['testsuite'][0],
      testcase: body['testsuite']['testcase'],
      classname: body['testsuite']['testcase'][0]['classname'],
      name: body['testsuite']['name'],
      tests: body['testsuite']['tests'],
      failures: body['testsuite']['failures'],
      time: body['testsuite']['time'],
  )
  status 201
  format_response(config, request.accept)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my testsuite and testcase properties to Object after seeing it wasn't printing correctly in my POST response, though testsuite is still showing up as null:

```
class SuiteConfiguration
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :testsuite, Object
  property :testcase, Object
  property :name, String
  property :tests, String
  property :failures, String
  property :time, String
  property :classname, String
end
```

And changed my post to get each value inside testcase

```
    post '/api/tests' do
  body = Crack::XML.parse request.body.read

  config = SuiteConfiguration.create(
      testcase: body['testsuite']['testcase'].each do |value|
        value          
      end,
      name: body['testsuite']['name'],
      tests: body['testsuite']['tests'],
      failures: body['testsuite']['failures'],
      time: body['testsuite']['time'],
  )
  status 201
  format_response(config, request.accept)
end
```

Now I get a GET request with the information I need from datamapper.